# Clamav configure: error: Your OpenSSL installation is missing the X509_VERIFY_PARAM function

Tags: compiling, openssl, ssl, clamav

I faced the below error when I installed the latest ClamAV AnitVirus (clamav-0.99.2) :

```
configure: error: Your OpenSSL installation is missing the X509_VERIFY_PARAM function
```

Details from Logs :

```
configure:18024: checking for X509_VERIFY_PARAM_new in -lssl
configure:18049: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing   conftest.c -lssl -lcrypto -lz  >&5
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .X509_VERIFY_PARAM_new

openssl version : OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016

which openssl : /usr/bin/openssl
```